# what does ProtocolException mean in jetty websocket?

Tags: websocket, jetty

When I try to send big text(about 40M) by using jetty websocket client, I got this ProtocolException:

org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.ProtocolException: Invalid control frame payload length, [142] cannot exceed [125]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.assertSanePayloadLength(Parser.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parseFrame(Parser.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.readParse(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I modified the maxTextMessageSize to make it to send big text. Any ideas why the ws is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.ProtocolException: Invalid control frame payload length, [142] cannot exceed [125]

That says the websocket implementation received a WebSocket Control Frame (CLOSE, PING, PONG) that had 142 bytes of payload, which is in violation of the WebSocket Spec (See [RFC6455 Section 5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5)), which limits Control Frames to only 125 bytes of payload.

The maxTextMessageSize only applies to the overall collected message size from Data Frames (TEXT, and 0 or more CONTINUATION frames)

Comment: do you have idea why the WS Control Frame have invalid size?

Comment: This could be from you using a bad implementation of WebSocket, or an old version of WebSocket against a new version of WebSocket.  Eg: Jetty 9.3.8 is the first stable version of WebSocket's permessage-deflate that works with the latest Chrome and Firefox fixes for permessage-deflate.